# Dropdown menu position is wrong and couldn't make the maps full height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating the following web app: https://mobigas.herokuapp.com/ and I'm having some problems with its css.

When you place your mouse over the "ENTRAR" link it displays the Sign In form in a wrong position (its left margin should be aligned to the left margin of the link).

And also, I tried to make the DIV with the map use the rest of the available visible area, but with no luck.

Here is the HTML of the menu and the CSS, however, I think looking at the Heroku link will be more helpful.

```
<div class="header-nav-main header-nav-main-light header-nav-main-effect-1 header-nav-main-sub-effect-1 collapse">
     <nav>
         <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
             <li class="dropdown dropdown-mega dropdown-mega-signin signin" id="headerAccount">
                 <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="page-login.html">
                     <i class="fa fa-user"></i> ENTRAR
                     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                 </a>
                 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li>
                         <div class="dropdown-mega-content">
                             <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-md-12"> <!--content-->
                                 </div>
                             </div>    
                         </div>
                      </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The map div is inside the `<div class="body">` below the `<header>` element.

```
<div role="main" class="main">
    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <div id="googlemaps" class="google-map full-height mt-none mb-sm"></div>
</div>
```

This is a customization of the Porto template I've bought on ThemeForest and it uses Bootstrap 3.

### UPDATE

Currently the `<li class="dropdown dropdown-mega dropdown-mega-signin signin">` element and the `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` are using position: static, and changing the dropdown-menu as another user suggested made the dropdown-menu smaller.

I've increase the width of the dropdown-menu and fixed the width of the `<a class="dropdown-toggle">`, but this made the Google Maps div to go down.

Answer (score 0):

Well first to the sign in Form:

You can achieve the postitioning by giving *.dropdown-menu* a relative position

```
.dropdown-menu{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

This way the position is calculated relative to the link.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion and it made the map to go down